# How can I get XML in bpmn-js/lib/Modeler at typescript react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I imported my `BPMN` `XML` in `Model` with `importXML` then I did set `bpmnModeler` to `bpmnModelerClone`.
if I want to get back `BPMN` from `bpmnModelerClone`, what should I do?

here is how I imported `XML` and set `bpmnModeler` to `bpmnModelerClone`

```
bpmnModeler.importXML(bpmnXML, (err:any) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('could not import BPMN 2.0 diagram', err);
    }
    const canvas = bpmnModeler.get('canvas');
    canvas.zoom('fit-viewport');
    });
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      bpmnModelerClone: bpmnModeler
    });
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

```
bpmnModelerClone.saveXML({ format: true }, (err: any, xml: any) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('could not export BPMN 2.0 diagram xml', err);
    }
    const xmlClone = xml;
    alert(xmlClone);
});
```